# C# How to Generate Random Number Depends on Probabilities

Tags: c#, .net, math, random, distributed-computing

I have a situation in which I must generate a random number, this number must be either `zero` or `one`

So, the code is something like this:

```
randomNumber = new Random().Next(0,1)
```

However, the business requirements state that there is just 10% probability that the generated number is zero and 90% probability that the generated number is 1

However can I include that probability in generating the random number please?

#### What I thought of is:

1. Generate array of integer that includes 10 zeros and 90 ones.
2. Generate a random index between 1 and 100
3. Take the value that corresponds to that index

But I don't know if this way is the correct way, plus, I think that C# should have something ready for it

Comment: Can't you just generate a number between 1 and 10 and then divide by 10? 9 times ... x/10 will be 0. 1 time x/10 will be one.

Comment: @ta.speot.is i don't know i am not good in math

Comment: `.Next(0,1)` This will generate 0 or 0. The max value is exclusive, not inclusive. Another thing: I hope you don't do a `new Random()` each time you do a `Next()`. It would be **wrong**

Comment: @xanatos that is a good point, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can implement it like that:

```
  // Do not re-create Random! Create it once only
  // The simplest implementation - not thread-save
  private static Random s_Generator = new Random();

  ...
  // you can easiliy update the margin if you want, say, 91.234%
  const double margin = 90.0 / 100.0; 

  int result = s_Generator.NextDouble() <= margin ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: Usage of double is smart. It prevents any confusion around `<` vs `<=`, as it becomes insignificant.

Comment: but in that case the `s_Generator` could generate numbers between `0` and `MaxDouble` right? in this case you are saying all the numbers bigger that 90 should be considered as one and the numbers smaller than 90 is zeros

Comment: @Dmitry It isnt insignificant. It is ony nearly insignificant. It should be <, because 1 is excluded

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Nope. It generates between 0.0 and 1.0 . See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.nextdouble(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Even if 1 was excluded, numbers from 0.0 to 0.9999 is just as good, which is exactly the reason there is almost no difference between `<` and `<=` in this solution (which is a good thing, coz who cares about signs and stuff)

Comment: @Euphoric You should be more precise *A double-precision floating point number that is greater than or equal to 0.0, and **less than 1.0.***

Comment: @YoryeNathan When you do a thing, you should do it correctly, otherwise a code reviewer will ask himself "does he know exactly how Random works and doesn't care, or what"

Comment: sorry guys i don't know what are you talking about, is it the `<=` should be `<`? or there is also another problem?

Comment: @xanatos If someone asked me just that, I'd ask him if he knows how math works, and tell him that I really, honestly don't care about whether it is `<` or `<=`, and that he can change it to whatever he prefers. Whatever is smoother on the eye. Math.

Answer (score 5):

to get true with a probability of 10%:

```
bool result = new Random().Next(1, 11) % 10 == 0;
```

to get true with a probability of 40%:

```
bool result = new Random().Next(1, 11) > 6;
```

Comment: can't you just do an `if` on the result ? if result > 6, then number = `1`, else number = `0` ?

Comment: @Random do you mean that is a solution to the 40% and 60% question?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli yes, i edited because it would be `> 6`instead of `>= 6`

Comment: Thanks for the efforts, i wish i could accept more than one answer, plus one

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should save the reference to the random instance in order to get a proper random sequence of numbers:

```
Random randGen = new Random();
```

The second thing to know, is that the max of the random is exclusive, so to properly solve the issue you should do:

```
int eitherOneOrZero = randGen.Next(1, 11) % 10;
```

To generalize it to any variation of chances, you can do:

```
Random randGen = new Random();
var trueChance = 60;

int x = randGen.Next(0, 100) < trueChance ? 1 : 0;
```

**Testing:**

```
Random randGen = new Random();
var trueChance = 60;

var totalCount = 1000;
var trueCount = 0;
var falseCount = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < totalCount; i++)
{
    int x = randGen.Next(0, 100) < trueChance ? 1 : 0;

    if (x == 1)
    {
        trueCount++;
    }
    else
    {
        falseCount++;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> True: 60.30 %
>
> False: 39.70 %

Comment: thanks but what if i changed the requirements to 40% zeros and 60% ones, could you give me a solution to that too?

Comment: *First of all, you should save the reference to the random instance in order to get a proper random sequence of numbers:* This is misleading, because `Random` is not thread safe. If you use the reference on different threads you might not get random numbers.

Comment: @ta.speot.is That is correct. However I doubt he's using multiple threads. But a good point to know. In case of multiple threads, each thread should keep a reference. You should definitely **not** create a new `Random` instance each time, though.

Comment: @YoryeNathan It is a little more complex than that. If each thread has a different `Random`, you must be sure they all use different seeds. Otherwise threads created nearly at the same time (in the same millisecond) will use the same seed.

Comment: @xanatos You could give each thread a random seed by one random instance in the parent thread. Making `Random` thread-safe is really not the point here though. I was pointing out that he shouldn't re-instantiate it each time.

Comment: For the record, my favorite solution for thread-safe random is `new Random((sharedRand.Next() ^ Thread.Current.Id) * Thread.Current.Id)`

Comment: Thanks for the efforts, i wish i could accept more than one answer, plus one